# In Azure Logic App how to iterate over a dictionary

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am having a Azure logic app where I want to iterate over a dictionary as shown below.

```
"test": {"text1":"qabdstw1234",
            "text2":"vhry46578"
            },
```

Here, in my Logic app I am able to iterate over a list of dictionary but here I want to iterate over a dictionary.

Does anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: So you want to pull out the Key/Value pairs and get the name of the property and it's value?  Is that right?  So instead of ... {"text1":"qabdstw1234", "text2":"vhry46578" } ... do you want ... [ { "Key": "text1", "Value": "qabdstw1234" }, { "Key": "text2", "Value": "vhry46578" } ] ...?

Comment: Because right now, you can't iterate over that JSON, it's not an array.

Comment: @Skin - Yes, initially we want to iterate over that json, but it seems it is not possible, so now we have made a list and passing dictionary within that list you have mentioned.

Comment: @svw1105 Can you please add your updated question

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT - Now, I am using a HTTP connector to invoke external API and in response it is giving below json.

Comment: {
  "title": "Incident ",
  "text1": [
    "arwtd@abc.com",
    "qwyrgcf@abc.com"
  ],
  "id": "1234",
  "status": "Success"
}

Comment: In the above HTTP body which I got as a response from a HTTP connector I want to fetch values of text1. So I am trying to use below expression but it says this expression is invalid.
triggerOutputs()?['body('http_connector')']?['text1']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used parse JSON inorder to fetch test1 data from the JSON which you have provided and then used compose connector to get the same. Here is my Logic app :-
[image]

Here is the generated schema while using the sample JSON Payload which you have provided I'm using:-

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "text1": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new action, search for *Control* and select the *For each*:

[image: Logic Apps for each]

> To process an array in your logic app, you can create a "Foreach" loop. This loop repeats one or more actions on each item in the array.

Source: [Create loops that repeat workflow actions or process arrays in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops)